# ExtJS 4.1 "HoverButton" extension issue

Tags: button, extjs, menu, hover, extjs4

I am working on an extension of Ext.Button that enables the showing/hiding of a button's menu on mouseover/mouseout. It is working perfectly for the button's immediate child menu, however I am running into an issue with having it behave properly for any secondary/tertiary/ect menus.

Right now, when the user moves over am item in the top menu that contains a menu, it will open the menu and the user can move the cursor into it with no problems, everything will stay open. If the user then moves the cursor out of the secondary menu into open space, all menus will close which is correct as well. BUT, sometimes if a user moves into a secondary menu, and then back into its parent menu, all the menus will close, which isn't what should happen, at the very least that parent menu that the cursor is now over should remain open.

From my initial debugging it looks to be an issue with how the events are firing, and their timing. It appears that the mouseenter event for a parent menu does not fire when moving from a child menu back into the parent menu. And secondly it looks to me like the the menu mouseover event does not fire reliably enough or often enough for it to cancel the delayed hide task after a mouseleave event on a child menu has fired.

Demo of the issue: http://qs1724.pair.com/users/autod1nx/EMPLOYEE/BDAMI/hoverbutton/index.html

And here's the code, does anything fundamentally wrong with it stand out?

```
Ext.define('Ext.HoverButton', {    
    extend: 'Ext.Button',
    alias: 'widget.hoverButton',
    isOver: false,
    hideDelay: 250,
    showDelay: 200,

    applyListeners: function(menu, cfg) {
        Ext.apply(menu, cfg);
        Ext.each(menu.items, function(item, idx, allItems) {
            if(item.menu) this.applyListeners(item.menu, cfg);
        }, this);
    },

    initComponent: function() {
        var config = {}, 
            menuConfig = {}, 
            me = this;

        me.delayedShowMenu = new Ext.util.DelayedTask(function() {
            if(!me.isOver) return;
            me.showMenu();
        }, this);

        me.delayedHideMenu = new Ext.util.DelayedTask(function() {
            if(me.isOver) return;
            me.hideMenu();
        });

        if(Ext.isDefined(this.initialConfig.menu)) {
            config = {
                listeners: {
                    mouseover: {
                        scope: me,
                        fn: function(b) {
                            me.isOver = true;
                            me.delayedShowMenu.delay(me.showDelay);
                        }
                    },
                    mouseout: {
                        scope: me,
                        fn: function(b) {
                            me.isOver = false;
                            me.delayedHideMenu.delay(me.hideDelay);
                        }
                    }
                }
            };

            menuConfig = {
                listeners: {
                    mouseover: {
                        scope: me,
                        fn: function(menu, item, e) {
                            me.delayedHideMenu.cancel();
                        }
                    },
                    mouseenter: {
                        scope: me,
                        fn: function(menu, e) {
                            me.delayedHideMenu.cancel();
                        }
                    },
                    mouseleave: {
                        scope: me,
                        fn: function(menu, e) {
                            me.delayedHideMenu.delay(me.hideDelay);
                        }
                    }
                }
            };


            //apply mouseover/leave listeners to all submenus recursively
            me.applyListeners(me.menu, menuConfig);      
        }

        Ext.apply(me, Ext.apply(me.initialConfig, config));
        Ext.HoverButton.superclass.initComponent.apply(me, arguments);
    }
});
```

Comment: Have you tried adding `me.isOver = true/false` to the menuConfig listener events?

Comment: I have yeah, didn't seem to make any difference. After more testing it looks like the issue lies in how the mouseover event is firing. In that is not really firing consistently or often enough to invoke the .cancel() on delayedHideMenu after the mouseleave event fires when leaving a sub menu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been doing something a bit similar and I've solved the problem after taking a peek at http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/mouseover.html

It seems that DOM's event order should be mouseover -> mouseenter -> mouseout -> mouseleave which means that sometimes the cancel() will be called before the delay() is set. To solve the problem I keep the last entered in a variable:

```
mouseenter: {
 scope: me,
 fn: function(menu, e) {
  presentlyInside = menu; /* << */
  me.delayedHideMenu.cancel();
 }
},
mouseleave: {
 scope: me,
 fn: function(menu, e) {
  if(presentlyInside==menu) /* << */
    me.delayedHideMenu.delay(me.hideDelay);
 }
}
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Interesting, its been awhile since I've touched this code, but will definitely have to give this a try next chance I get. Thanks for the response!

Comment: I've only got it work a few minutes before posting the anwser, but so far in my implementation (and on Chrome) I haven't found any glitches.

Comment: I know this response is VERY belated, but I finally updated the extension with your fix and it works like a champ! thanks again!!

Comment: Not working for me, menu disappears suddenly... kindly post full code here

Answer (score 4):

I found this one works, and more simple.

```
Ext.define('Ext.HoverButton', {
extend    : 'Ext.Button',
alias     : 'widget.hoverButton',
listeners : {
        mouseover : function() {
            this.showMenu();
        },
        menushow : function() {
            this.mouseLeaveMonitor = this.menu.el.monitorMouseLeave(100, this.hideMenu, this);
        },
        destroy : function(combo) {
            combo.menu.el.un(combo.mouseLeaveMonitor);
        }
    }
});
```