# toolbar menus auto dropdown on mouse hover in extjs 4

Tags: extjs, drop-down-menu, extjs4, extjs4.2

I have a toolbar button, that when clicked, displays a menu, i want it to be auto. i.e. dropdown menu on mouse hover. I've done this by the following code:

```
xtype : 'button',
                text : 'My Button',
                listeners : {
                    mouseover : function() {
                        console.log('inside mouse over');
                        this.showMenu();
                    },
                    menushow : function() {
                        console.log('menu shown');
                        this.mouseLeaveMonitor = this.menu.el
                                .monitorMouseLeave(100, this.hideMenu, this);
                    },
                    destroy : function(combo) {
                        combo.menu.el.un(combo.mouseLeaveMonitor);
                    }
                },
                menu : [{
                            text : 'menu item1'
                        }, {
                            text : 'menu item2', menu : [{text : 'text 1'}, {text : 'text 2'}]
                        }]
```

Well, my code works fine for dropdown menu, but it fails in submenu. Can anyone help on this?

Answer (score 1):

You can only using this and that should working

```
xtype : 'button',
text : 'My Button',
listeners : {
    mouseover : function() {
        console.log('inside mouse over');
        this.showMenu();
    }
},
menu : [{
    text : 'menu item1'
}, {
    text : 'menu item2', menu : [{text : 'text 1'}, {text : 'text 2'}]
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this person was trying to accomplish the same thing as you: [ExtJS 4.1 "HoverButton" extension issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10505095/extjs-4-1-hoverbutton-extension-issue)

The difference you will need to add is to have your menu configured as an object config, not as an array of items:

```
{
    xtype: 'hoverButton',
    text : 'My Button',
    menu : {
        items: [{
            text : 'menu item1'
        }, {
            text : 'menu item2',
            menu : {
                items: [{text : 'text 1'}, {text : 'text 2'}]
            }
        }]
    }
}
```

Comment: See my edits, I was able to get this working by doing it this way.  HTH.